# Running terraform plan through sops exec-file

Tags: terraform, mozilla-sops

I have an encrypted `providers.tfvars.json`, so running:

`sops exec-file provider.tfvars.json 'terraform plan -var-file={} -out terraform.todo'`

I expect terraform to work correctly, but I get an error from terraform:

`Error: Argument or block definition required`

Decrypting `providers.tfvars.json`, and running `terraform plan -var-file=provider.tfvars.json -out terraform.todo` works

I tried `sops exec-file --no-fifo` to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in sops version [`3.7.0`](https://github.com/mozilla/sops/releases/tag/v3.7.0) with [PR #761](https://github.com/mozilla/sops/pull/761)

Terraform needs a filename extension for var files, sops didn’t provide one.